# Using scanf with x86-64 GAS assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, scanf, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I have been having loads of issues trying to get a call the the system function scanf to work in my x86 assembly program. Currently I have got it to read from standard in however, it only will read chars without a segfault (I have no idea why, the specifying string is %d). The examples I've seen of scanf in x86 online use quarky or are written with NASM syntax, thus I have tried to adapt them for my program.

```
f:
    .string "%d"

_main:
    movq    $0,    %rax    #Clean rax
    movq    $f,    %rdi    #Load string format
    movq    %rcx,  %rsi    #Set storage to rcx (Not sure if this is valid)
    call    scanf
    ret
```

Checking rcx and rax using printf return 1 and 0 respectively after inputting a char or string (only way the program doesn't segfault).

Any insight on how to us scanf properly in x86 gas assembly would be very much appreciated!

Comment: `scanf` is a *standard library* function, not a "system function". And for the second argument, it is expecting a memory address into which the result will be stored. You can mov a register value into RSI and expect it to store data in the previous register - that doesn't make any sense. Use LEA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you feared, `movq %rcx, %rsi` is not correct. You need to pass a pointer to memory. Registers are not part of the memory address space and thus you can't have pointers to them. You need to allocate storage either globally or locally. Incidentally, you should not put your data (especially writable) into the default `.text` section, as that is intended for code and is typically read-only. Also, calling convention usually mandates 16 byte stack pointer alignment, so you should take care of that too.

```
.globl main

main:
    push %rbp           # keep stack aligned
    mov  $0, %eax       # clear AL (zero FP args in XMM registers)
    leaq f(%rip), %rdi  # load format string
    leaq x(%rip), %rsi  # set storage to address of x
    call scanf
    pop %rbp
    ret

.data

f:  .string "%d"         # could be in .rodata instead
x:  .long 0
```

(If your environment expects a leading underscore on symbols, then use `_main`, and probably `_scanf`.)

---

There are actually 3 choices for putting addresses of symbols / labels into registers.  RIP-relative LEA is the standard way on x86-64.  [How to load address of function or label into register in GNU Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register-in-gnu-assembler)

As an optimization if your variables are in the lower 4GiB of the address space, e.g. in a Linux non-PIE (position-*dependent*) executable, you can use 32-bit absolute immediates:

```
    mov  $f, %edi       # load format string
    mov  $x, %esi       # set storage to address of x
```

`movq $f, %rdi` would use a 32-bit sign-extended immediate (instead of implicit zero-extension into RDI from writing EDI), but has the same code-size as a RIP-relative LEA.

You can also load the full 64 bit absolute address using the mnemonic `movabsq`.  But don't do that because a 10-byte instruction is bad for code-size, and still needs a runtime fixup because it's not position-independent.

```
    movabsq $f, %rdi # load format string
    movabsq $x, %rsi # set storage to address of x
```

---

Upon request: **using a local variable for the output could look like:**

```
    subq  $8, %rsp       # allocate 8 bytes from stack
    xor   %eax, %eax     # clear AL (and RAX)
    leaq  f(%rip), %rdi  # load format string
    movq  %rsp, %rsi     # set storage to local variable
    call  scanf
    addq  $8, %rsp       # restore stack
    ret
```

Comment: Thank you very much! For future reference how would I replace global x with just local memory space?

Comment: @user3210373: `lea 4(%rsp), %rsi` for example.  Or `mov %rsp, %rsi` if your local happens to be at `(%rsp)`.  [My (AT&T) assembly (x86-x64) code should increment but doesn't](//stackoverflow.com/q/46389957) shows an example.

Comment: Ugh, `mov $f, %edi` for low addresses (Linux non-PIE executable), otherwise `lea f(%rip), %rdi`.  `movq` or `movabs` are not good suggestions.